# How to get multiple target android level in eclipse IDE?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

While developing an andriod application in Eclipse IDE, the target level is set to 4.4 and I am not getting any option of lower levels of andriod. If I start building the add on higher version.. will my app is executable in lower version devices ?

Comment: No you have minimum and maximum sdk level of android version you need to support which you define in AndroidManifest of your application as follows:

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


Please provide screenshots of your sdk and other details so we can help

Answer (score 0):

check your SDK manager, do you have other API version
[image]

your app will executable in your minimum SDK setting in your app
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html